# Running ssh client as root always uses /root/.ssh instead of ~/.ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I am logged into a Linux (Debian stretch) server as root. When I run the ssh client as root it appears that the ssh client insists on using `/root/.ssh/` as the location of all the ssh configuration and key files rather than `~/.ssh`:

```
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ export HOME=/srv/scratch/user
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ pwd
/srv/scratch/user/.ssh
$ ssh -vvv git@example.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2t  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for example.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
... more lines that never mention /srv/scratch/user/.ssh ...
```

Why is the ssh client not using the `.ssh` directory in `/srv/scratch/user`?

Comment: Maybe `root` is a special user account and it does not create the path toward the `.ssh` directory using the `~/.ssh` expression as you have expected it to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
export HOME=/srv/scratch/user
```

`ssh` doesn't use the `HOME` environment variable to find the user's home directory. It calls [`getpwuid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwuid.html) and uses the home directory returned from that. `getpwuid()` returns the user information from `/etc/passwd` or wherever your particular system stores user information.

You can get ssh to read a different config file using the [`-F`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#F) option:

> **-F** configfile
>   Specifies an alternative per-user configuration file. If a configuration file is given on the command line, the system-wide
>   configuration file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) will be ignored. The default
>   for the per-user configuration file is ~/.ssh/config.

You can specify ssh keys using [`-i`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#i):

> **-i** identity_file
>   Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read. The default is
>   ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.
>   Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the
>   configuration file. It is possible to have multiple -i options (and
>   multiple identities specified in configuration files). If no
>   certificates have been explicitly specified by the CertificateFile
>   directive, ssh will also try to load certificate information from the
>   filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to identity filenames.

Note that if you run a command using "~" to specify a filename, like this:

```
ssh -F ~/some/config/file ...
```

then the "~" will be interpreted by your shell, not by ssh.